# Get SSL certificate for Tableau

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, tableau-api, tableau-desktop

I can't connect with my Tableau Server from Tableau Desktop because it shows me that error: `SSL certificate is not valid`. I'm searching for a solution, but I'm only reading how to change the certificate with another, beacause I do not have any other certificate.

My question goes before that: how can I get a certificate? where I can get it from?

Comment: Are you sure that this error is shown in Tableau Desktop and not in Tableau Server?

Comment: @Nicolaesse it is shown whenever I try to connect my server from Tableau Desktop. Probably you're, right, the problem exists in the server, but the log shows itself in Desktop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the guide from Tableau I use whenever I need to setup SSL for my servers. It includes obtaining an SSL Certificate from a certificate authority [Steps for SSL Cert](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ssl_cert_create.htm)

To configure Tableau Server to use SSL, you must have an SSL certificate. To obtain the SSL certificate, complete the steps:

1. [Set the OpenSSL configuration environment variable (optional)](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ssl_cert_create.htm#Set)
2. [Generate a key file](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ssl_cert_create.htm#generate-key)
3. [Create a Certificate Signing Request (CSR)](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ssl_cert_create.htm#generate-csr)
4. [Send the CSR to a certificate authority (CA) to obtain an SSL certificate](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ssl_cert_create.htm#send-csr)
5. [Use the key and certificate to configure Tableau Server to use SSL](https://help.tableau.com/current/server/en-us/ssl_cert_create.htm#config-server)